# Very simple question about max signed int value

Tags: c++

So I feel incredibly stupid for even having to ask this idk what's wrong with my brain but say I have some 32 bit int right? There are 2 possible numbers that can go in each bit and also one bit goes to the sign so I have 31 bits now, 2^31 is the amount of combinations  I can create with putting all the 0's and 1's in different places but why does this mean that 2^31-1 is like the MAX number? I can create 2^31 different combinations but this technically doesn't mean that 2^31-1 is even gonna be a number does it? And let alone the biggest one?

Comment: Because `0` is a possible value.

Comment: "and also one bit goes to the sign" - not quite. From C++20 onwards (and very likely before then), an `int` is a 2's complement type. That gives you an extra negative number in place of a signed negative zero.

Comment: Still not really answering my main question though I have like 2.1 billion possible negative and positive combinations, all I have are those combinations right? That could be like random numbers literally any numbers how do I know that the biggest possible number it can hold is also the total amount of positive/negative combinations -1?

Comment: Personally I'd contract the question to a smaller 8 bit 2's complement `signed char`. Its range is -128 to +127. Study the bit pattern for the negative values. The range for your larger type will be obvious then.

Comment: To add to @Bathsheba: With 2's complement, there are 128 negative values (-128 ... -1) and 128 positive values (0 ... 127). As the 0 occupies one of the available bit patterns (the one where every bit is 0), it has to be counted as well. So, there are 128 + 128 = 256 = 2^8 numbers encoded, and that's the maximum which can be achieved with 8 binary bits.

Comment: And there are no gaps, so we cannot have `[0..63][200..263]` for the 128 positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks that no gap part is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might be interesting:

```
g++     Foo.cpp   -o Foo
Foo: 2147483647
Bar: -2147483648
$ cat Foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **) {
    int foo = 0x7fffffff;
    int bar = 0x7fffffff;

    bar += 1;
    std::cout << "Foo: " << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bar: " << bar << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not sure if it demonstrates what you're asking, but it demonstrates *something* :-)

Comment: Signed int overflow is UB, so it demonstrates.. nothing...

Comment: @Jarod42 You probably missed the point if you believe that. It demonstrates that foo is max int (at least using my version of G++ on my hardware). It demonstrates the bit pattern of max int. It demonstrates max negative int, and one can at least guess the bit pattern of that, too. Whether that helps the OP, I'm not sure, as I'm not sure where the real confusion is.

Comment: Code exhibiting UB can do whatever, compilers might discard the full branch for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 Would you have felt better if I'd defined bar as 0x80000000 without the overflow to get it there? Would suddenly this have gone to a dismissive attitude on your part to demonstrating what I think it already demonstrates?

Comment: `0x80'00'00'00` would have been fine since 2 complement is mandatory (C++20) (previously, value was implementation specific).